# Display a TreeViewItem above its siblings

Tags: silverlight, treeview, treeviewitem

For my Silverlight 4 application I use a treeview with user defined items. A feature of those items is, that they can display a stackpanel, which is placed **below** the item itself. (I use a negative margin to move the stackpanel in the desired position.) The problem with this is, that the stackpanel (or the treeviewitem itself for that matter) have to be visually placed "above" the other treeviewitems.

The stackpanel is only shown when a (toggle)button in the treeviewitem is pressed, so I used the check/uncheck event to change the Z-Value of the containing header:

```
// up the Z-Axis of the containing header (a button) 
Button header = VisualTreeEnumeration.FindUpVisualTree<Button>(sender as MultiImageToggleButton);
header.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 1);
```

This works only, when the treeviewitem, that the stackpanel shall be displayed above is in the lower hierarchy level. When the treeviewitem is on the same level, it is not placed above.

Does anyone know how to display an treeviewitem above (regarding ZIndex) an other treeviewitem at the same level?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

The answer already lies in the question "... how to display an treeviewitem above ..."! Find that treeviewitem and set the ZValue:

```
TreeViewItem tvi = VisualTreeEnumeration.FindUpVisualTree<TreeViewItem>(sender as MultiImageToggleButton);
tvi.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 1);
```